# Имитировать клик при парсинге

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

Провожу парсинг сайта, используя phpQuery. Требуется получить элемент, который появляется после ajax-запроса со страницы-источника. Отдельно сделать ajax-запрос не представляется возможным (на странице хитро генерируется token через ключ, разобрать который не получается, используется при обращении в ajax).
Возможно ли удаленное нажатие на кнопку через phpQuery или через какой-либбо другой инструмент?

Comment: как вариант в одном курле загрузить страничку и затем ajax-запрос с полученным токеном, а там уже смотреть, потому как защита может быть не только токеном, но и сессией, куками и тд.

Comment: `phpQuery` вам тут явно не поможет.

Comment: Selenium вам поможет.

Comment: @Axenow посмотрел selenium, по ходу запустить эту связку можно только на домашнем компе, так как требуется файрфокс, как такое будет работать на шареде не представляю))

Comment: @Axenow Я попробовал развернуть и запустить на VPS. И практически удачно. Кстати, там можно и под хром это дело запустить. Но встретился с некоторыми ошибками, которые преодолеть не смог и, честно говоря, подзабил на это дело. Пока оставлю задачу нерешенной.